# Flutter Transform Positioned widget Left to Right when i click the button and make it visible?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

**What i need?**

I have two Positioned Widget inside of the Stack Widget. Once i click the TextButton i'd like to transform one positioned widget right to left and display another invisible widget on the screen.

Also once i click the another TextButton it should be like in the initial view.

I have tried what have described in this video but couldn't work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCyoHclCqc8

**Details in the below code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        FormLogin(),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class FormLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormLogin({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormLoginState createState() => _FormLoginState();
}

class _FormLoginState extends State<FormLogin>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static AnimationController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      flex: 2,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [Color(0xFFbe8696), Color(0xFFbe8996)],
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // Logo Section -> I don't want to transform this section i want to keep it on screen.
          Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.8,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Image.network(
                  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png/799px-Google-flutter-logo.png",
                  scale: 4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          // Login Screen - I would like to transfer this Positioned Widget through  
          // X axis to left and make it invisible, When I click the below TextButton.
          Positioned(
              top: 200,
              child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    elevation: 0.7,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 4),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Wrap(
                                runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  TextButton(
                                    // When I click that button.
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Signup",
                                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        fontSize: 14.0,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ))),

          // Register Screen - Once user click the above button, 
          // at the same time this widget should be visible.
          Positioned(
              top: 250,

          // This widget invisible now. Make "left: 0" to display widget.
              left: 0,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    elevation: 0.7,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 4),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child: Wrap(
                                runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  TextButton(
                                    //**I would like to return initial position once i click that button.**
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Return Back",
                                      style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        fontSize: 14.0,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  )))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check `AnimatedPositioned `/ `PositionedTransition` widgets

Comment: @pskink I d like to move LoginScreen outside of the page and its not possible with the PositionedTransition.. I still need help..